# Why I'm getting Swift_TransportException: Unable to connect with TLS encryption in Server?

Tags: php, email, phalcon, swiftmailer

I have migrated to new server from old server. There are quite changes in new server. Old server was using PHP `5.6` and phalcon `3.2` and new server is using PHP `7.3` & phalcon `3.4.4`.

In old server email sending is working smoothly but in new server it's throwing the below error:

> Swift_TransportException: Unable to connect with TLS encryption

Server Mail configuration in both sites are:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

NOTE: Old site was on `http` and new site is on `https`

Comment: If it's a different server with a different OS or OS version, make sure the new server has all the necessary certificates installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 35 hours research and with the help of our great team finally found the solution :)

**SMTP restriction was enabled on our server from WHM**. After disabling the SMTP restriction the error was gone.

You can find this in WHM by searching `SMTP` and it will be available under security center. Disable it and this error will be no more.

[image: smtp restrictions snap]